# Android emulator never loads in Ubuntu 11

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, emulation, qemu

I've posted a similar question with a similar problem but on windows XP. So i installed ubuntu 11 and this>
sun-jdk 6, sun-jre 6, eclipse galileo, adt plugin and the android sdk.
Not even the 1.5 android target device works. Just loads forever, reaching the flashing android word screen and it goes on and on. I let it load for a hour and nothing changes.
What's the checklist to make this run? I am very dissapointed with this situation.

Specs> Athlon 64x2 3600+, ram = 1.5 Gb

I made the default 1.5 target device, another one with 2.3.3 and 256 ram, and another one with 2.1 and defaults.

Comment: No idea, but what are the specs of your machine and how long do you wait and what are the specs of the virtual device that you create?

Comment: Sorry for omitting that, the specs are added to the question.

Comment: run 'emulator -verbose @avdname' to see what's happening.

Comment: This is also happening to me as well. I have tried from the command line and from a new AVD in Eclipse. The window appears and the verbose output last shows "ping command: ... ddms ping emulator". Just sits there.

Comment: Just buy an android device, that did it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinstalled the jvm and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get in console when you launch eclipse by hand and launch adt ?

What is the jre/jdk used to launch eclipse ? (ps fax | grep eclipse)

Stéphane

Comment: I'm launching the emulator from the SDK Manager with the same results. I'd set the default jre to sun java 6 and the same with the jdk. This is the result from the command you gave>  6586 pts/0    S+     0:00                  \_ grep --color=auto eclipse

Comment: Please add this as a comment rather than an answer. @Snicolas

Answer (score 0):

Once the animation comes up you should be able to get an adb connection to the emulator and use the adb shell or adb logcat output, this will let you know if it's still doing setup tasks such as dexopting packages, if it's dead, or if the android runtime is stuck in a crash and restart loop.